# Get key value of command

Tags: macros, pdfpages, tex4ht, key-value

i'm beginner in Tex 
and i have tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength{\jot}{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{chestnutStem}
In the following figure, if the spinner is divided into 8 colored sections, what is the probability of it stopping at blue?

\centerline{\includepdf[page=2]{mypdf.pdf}}

\end{chestnutStem}

\chestnutKey{
$        \frac{1}{4}      $
}

\begin{chestnutAnswer}

        \begin{align*}
        \textrm{The probability of the spinner stopping at blue}&=\frac{\textrm{the number of blue sections}}{\textrm{total number of sections}}\\
        &=\frac{2}{8}\\
        &=\frac{1}{4}.
        \end{align*}

\end{chestnutAnswer}

\end{document}
```

and i have cls file

```
\ProvidesClass{chestnut}[2016/02/17]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareStringOption{country}{}
\DeclareStringOption{language}{}
\DeclareStringOption{math}{}
\DeclareStringOption{numerals}{}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\DeclareOption{example}{%
\typeout{You are using example object.}

}%

\DeclareOption*{}{}
\ProcessOptions*\relax

\RequirePackage[lmargin=0.5in,rmargin=0.5in,tmargin=0.5in,bmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\let\country=\chestnut@country
\typeout{ Your country \country}

\let\language=\chestnut@language
\typeout{ Your language \language}

\let\math=\chestnut@math
\typeout{ Your symbols language is \math}

\let\numerals = \chestnut@numerals
\typeout{ Your numerals are in \numerals}

\newenvironment{chestnutStem}{\underline{\textbf{Stem}}\\* }{\hfill \\* }

\newcommand\chestnutKey[1]{\underline{\textbf{Key}}\\*#1\hfill\\* }

\newenvironment{chestnutAnswer}{\underline{\textbf{Answer}}\\*}{\hfill \\* }

\RequirePackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand\chestnutTikZ[1]{\includepdf[pages=-,width=.9\textwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\IfFileExists{approved.jpg}{%
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand\headrule{}
\rhead{\vspace{0.5in}\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{approved.png}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
}%
```

and alternative4ht.sty file

```
\ProvidesPackage{alternative4ht}

\newcommand{\altusepackage}[2][]{%
    \ifx\HCode\relax%
    \usepackage[#1]{#2}%
    \else%
    \IfFileExists{#2-alt4ht.sty}{%
      \usepackage[#1]{#2-alt4ht}%
    }{\typeout{alternative4ht: no patch file for #2}}
    \fi%
}
\endinput
```

and pdfpages-alt4ht.sty file

```
\ProvidesPackage{pdfpages-alt4ht}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\includepdf[2][]{%
    \includegraphics{#2}
}

\endinput
```

and cfg file to convert pdf pages to png images

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
  \Configure{graphics*}  
         {pdf}  
         {\Needs{"convert -scene 1 \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
                               \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}%  
          \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png}% here i want add page number with pdf file name for example <mypdf-2.png>
          \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
         }  
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I want get [page] value option in `\includepdf` command to use it in config file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Sorry, your question is totally unclear! Your example seems to be some special markup that creates a `LaTeX` file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will! In this case you should point out that this is a tex4ht issue.

Comment: Your question poses more questions than you might realize. Here are some: How did you come to have this command? How did you come to have a `.cfg` file? What does it configure, exactly? Is your `\includepdf` command from `pdfpages`?  Please read the link Andrew posted and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: why do you have `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}` in there?

Comment: @Nasser to include meta-data i need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdfpages` is one of packages which causes `tex4ht` to fail once they are included. In this case, TeX source must be altered, which is something that we try to avoid with `tex4ht`. [helpers4ht bundle](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) provides `\altusepackage` command, which can be used to load alternative version of packages for `tex4ht`. These alternative packages are named `packagename-alt4ht.sty`. They contain definitions for macros used in the document. Definition for `pdfpages` was only basic, it could be used to include only one paged pdf document.

To support multipage pdf files, I've added `pages` option to `\includepdf` command in `pdfpages-alt4ht.sty` package. It doesn't support all features of original, as it would be quite difficult to implement it and I don't think that it makes sense in HTML output:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pdfpages-alt4ht}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@key{includepdf}{pages}{\edef\current@pdf@page{\the\numexpr #1-1\relax}}

\newcommand\includepdf[2][]{%
  \def\current@pdf@page{0}
    \setkeys*{includepdf}{#1}
    \filename@parse{#2}
    \def\current@png@name{\filename@area\filename@base-\current@pdf@page.png}
    \IfFileExists{\current@png@name}{}{%
      \Needs{"convert #2[\current@pdf@page]
      \current@png@name"}
    }
    \includegraphics{\current@png@name}
  }

  \endinput
```

it saves requested page in `\current@pdf@page` macro, it must be decremented by 1, because `imagemagick` counts pages from 0. The `png` name is constructed as `imagename-pagenumber.png` and `convert` program is called only if it doesn't exist yet.

I had to fix one issue in `chestnut.cls`, there was missing `{}` in `IfFileExists`:

```
\ProvidesClass{chestnut}[2016/02/17]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareStringOption{country}{}
\DeclareStringOption{language}{}
\DeclareStringOption{math}{}
\DeclareStringOption{numerals}{}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\DeclareOption{example}{%
\typeout{You are using example object.}

}%

\DeclareOption*{}{}
\ProcessOptions*\relax

\RequirePackage[lmargin=0.5in,rmargin=0.5in,tmargin=0.5in,bmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\let\country=\chestnut@country
\typeout{ Your country \country}

\let\language=\chestnut@language
\typeout{ Your language \language}

\let\math=\chestnut@math
\typeout{ Your symbols language is \math}

\let\numerals = \chestnut@numerals
\typeout{ Your numerals are in \numerals}

\newenvironment{chestnutStem}{\underline{\textbf{Stem}}\\* }{\hfill \\* }

\newcommand\chestnutKey[1]{\underline{\textbf{Key}}\\*#1\hfill\\* }

\newenvironment{chestnutAnswer}{\underline{\textbf{Answer}}\\*}{\hfill \\* }

\RequirePackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand\chestnutTikZ[1]{\includepdf[pages=-,width=.9\textwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\IfFileExists{approved.jpg}{%
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand\headrule{}
\rhead{\vspace{0.5in}\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{approved.png}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
}{}%
```

and also your TeX file, because `chestnut` class wasn't used:

```
\documentclass{chestnut}

\addtolength{\jot}{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{chestnutStem}
In the following figure, if the spinner is divided into 8 colored sections, what is the probability of it stopping at blue?

\centerline{\includepdf[pages=2]{mypdf.pdf}}

\end{chestnutStem}

\chestnutKey{
$        \frac{1}{4}      $
}

\begin{chestnutAnswer}

        \begin{align*}
        \textrm{The probability of the spinner stopping at blue}&=\frac{\textrm{the number of blue sections}}{\textrm{total number of sections}}\\
        &=\frac{2}{8}\\
        &=\frac{1}{4}.
        \end{align*}

\end{chestnutAnswer}

\end{document}
```

sample output:

[image]